# C# UWP Visual Studio : trying to erase last char from string

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to have the final char of the string erased if it's not a number. I commented out one line that says a="hi";, however it does fire if I enter any letter. So I know the logic is right, but I just can't get it to erase the char if it's a letter. I'm trying to have this textbox only allow number char in the string because I'm going to use it for math equations later. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void NameField_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
            string a = NameField.Text;

            int b = a.Length - 1;
            char c = a[b];

            if(!Char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                //a = "Hi";
                a.Remove(b);
                NameField.Text = a;

                Tester.Text = a;
            }
}
```

Comment: The problem why it don'd delete the char is, that your code do not process the result of the removed char. You need change to remove line to: `a = a.Remove(b);` Second problem is, that the user entered character must not be the last character in string.

Comment: Yea Julo you were right. changing it to a = a.Remove(b) definitely deletes any non numeric character

Comment: Alexei Levenkov I was asking for a way to do this. I simply added my code to get some guidance, but I was thinking that Remove wasn't the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove function takes **startindex** to remove the string content. pass the index from where to be removed and you can also send count.

string value= "hello";
string removedvalue = value.Remove(value.Length - 1);